# Get STDOUT, STDERR without waiting for process to exit

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stderr

Some processes exit after a long time and their status is constantly being written to STDOUT.

How can I run a process and read its STDOUT without waiting for the process to exit?

I tried:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
o = p.communicate()[0] # Waits until process exits, also tried p.stdout.read()
print o                # Isn't printed until process exists
do_something(o)        # Doesn't get executed until process exits
```

Comment: There are several solutions depending on what you want. Do you want to process the stdout as it arrives, or just let it finish in the background while you do something else? Is the command outputing line oriented text? Does the command behave differently if it is run on the console or in a batch file? Is this windows or linux? Do you want to run multiple commands in parallel?

Comment: Process the stdout every n seconds (whatever has been written by the process upto that moment), outputting line oriented text, same behaviour anyway it's run, Windows, want to run multiple commands in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Reading line by line is straight forward

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
for line in p.stdout:
    do work here
p.wait()
if p.returncode != 0:
    panic here
```

...mostly. Commands tend to buffer differently depending on whether they are run from a conole or another program. Since you are not a console, you may find that it outputs less often...  but it'll all eventually get there before the program exits. On linux you can use pty or pexpect or something, but I know of no good solution on windows.

Now if you want to run them in parallel, create a thread per command you run and thread.join() each of them at the end of your programming. This is a bit tricky in itself. You could use a thread pool (see multiprocessing.ThreadPool on python 2.x, don't remember the name off hand in 3.x).